# tabularray and wrong display

Tags: beamer, tabularray

I don't know why I don't have a nice tableau in `beamer`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\title{Phénomènes aléatoires}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Fréquences conditionnelles en colonne}

La fréquence conditionnelle $f_{R}(P)=0,56$.

Cela signifie que, parmi la sous-population de référence des élèves refusés (R)  (\textbf{c'est la condition}) environ 56 \% viennent des séries professionnelles.

\begin{center}

\begin{tblr}{
colspec={Q[3cm,c] Q[2.5cm,c] },
rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] },
 cell{1}{2}={gray!10} , cell{5}{1}={red!10}
}
\SetHline{2-2}{black,.5pt}
\SetVline{2-5}{black,.5pt}  
 &  \SetVline{1-5}{black,.5pt} Refusé R  &  \SetVline{1-5}{black,.5pt}  
\\
\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}  

Série générale G & $\dfrac{14741}{65126}=0,23$
\\
\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}  

Série pro P &  $\dfrac{13687}{65126}=0,21$ 
\\
\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}  

Série techno P &  $\dfrac{36698}{65126}=0,56$ 
\\
\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}  

Total & 1 
\\
\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}

\end{tblr}
\end{center}



 
\end{exampleblock}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. So far it contain some errors as undefined `\ier` command (if I insert it in some fresh  `beamer` fragment. BTW, your table code is a bit strange ...

Comment: Showed table image is not close to your code content ... Please show us what you get from compilation of your code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code can't compile; see comments

Comment: Dear close voters: the OP has edited their question in the mean time. Now the code is compileable and reproduces the problem shown in image.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, yes it is, but after receive my answer and after my deleting his answer ... Before it, he not react to comments nor provide any excuse or thankfulness for it. So for me, his edit is to late ....

Comment: @Zarko You can avoid such frustrating situations by waiting until a question is clear. As a rule of thumb: if an answer starts with "I guess" and ends with "please add a MWE", this might be signs that a question is not yet ready for an answer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you very much for your response. I was not be frustrated, rather sad how the OP is behaving (I expected at least a comment to my answer and an apology for the confusion in his question). About waiting ... it seems that the best way to avoid such situations in future, would be simple to quit my participation on this site :-( and not try to help questioners as quick as possible also with guessing what they are after when their questions are not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `\SetHline{1-4}{black,.5pt}` you tell tabularray to draw your lines over four columns, which is wider than the two columns your table uses.

You will get a nice looking table if you use `\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\title{Phénomènes aléatoires}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Fréquences conditionnelles en colonne}

La fréquence conditionnelle $f_{R}(P)=0,56$.

Cela signifie que, parmi la sous-population de référence des élèves refusés (R)  (\textbf{c'est la condition}) environ 56 \% viennent des séries professionnelles.

\begin{center}

\begin{tblr}{
colspec={Q[3cm,c] Q[2.5cm,c] },
rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] },
 cell{1}{2}={gray!10} , cell{5}{1}={red!10}
}
\SetHline{2-2}{black,.5pt}
\SetVline{2-5}{black,.5pt}  
 &  \SetVline{1-5}{black,.5pt} Refusé R  &  \SetVline{1-5}{black,.5pt}  
\\
\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}  

Série générale G & $\dfrac{14741}{65126}=0,23$
\\
\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}  

Série pro P &  $\dfrac{13687}{65126}=0,21$ 
\\
\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}  

Série techno P &  $\dfrac{36698}{65126}=0,56$ 
\\
\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}  

Total & 1 
\\
\SetHline{1-2}{black,.5pt}

\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated to your question: You don't need to load all the `ams*` packages, beamer already loads them for you.

Comment: thx a lot !best

Comment: @michaelbriffoteaux You're welcome! Have fun with tabularray and beamer!

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is a way (rather easy) to create that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\title{Phénomènes aléatoires}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Fréquences conditionnelles en colonne}

La fréquence conditionnelle $f_{R}(P)=\num{0,56}$.

Cela signifie que, parmi la sous-population de référence des élèves refusés (R)  (\textbf{c'est la condition}) environ 56 \% viennent des séries professionnelles.

\begin{center}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines,corners,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{red!10}{5-1}
  \cellcolor{gray!10}{1-2}
\Body
                   &  Refusé R \\
  Série générale G & $\dfrac{14741}{65126}=\num{0,23}$ \\
  Série pro P      & $\dfrac{13687}{65126}=\num{0,21}$ \\
  Série techno P   & $\dfrac{36698}{65126}=\num{0,56}$ \\
  Total            & 1 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{center}
 
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: In order to have correct spaces around the comma used as decimal separator (as done in France), I have use `num` of `siunitx` with the key `locale = FR`.

Comment: As an alternative to get correct spacing around the comma, one could also use the `icomma` package

Comment: thx a lot :) again :)

Answer (score 0):

Showed fragment od code and image of table are not related, so it is unclear what is your problem:

- Are you after for code which produce showed image, or
- you looking for fix of provided code.
  So far I focused on code fragment. -
- Unfortunately it contains undefined commands `\ier{}` and `\ieme`  so I not used them in MWEs' below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%   \UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth} % not used in this MWE

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize
\frametitle{Example of \texttt{tabularray} table}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1} = {2-Z}{solid}, hline{2-Z}={1-Z}{solid},
                 vline{1}   = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{2-Z}={1-Z}{solid},
                 colspec = {X[3,l] * {5}{X[c]} },
                 colsep  = {4pt},
                 rows    = {m}
                 }
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Participation aux législatives
        &   &   &   &   \\
Participation aux législatives
    &   A tous les tours
        &   Au 1  tour
            &   Au 2 tour
                &   Aucun
                    &   Total               \\
A tous les tours
    & 0,65  & 2,84  &       & 3,10  &       \\
Au 1{} tour
    &  0,13 & 0,29  & 0,26  & 0,08  &       \\
Au 2 tour
    &       & 1,13  & 1,25  & 0,60  & 0,36  \\
Total
    &       & 4,26  &       & 3,78  & 1,90  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Is this close what you after?
- If not, please, consider my comments below your question and provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document (similar to my above MWE) with correct code of the desired table.

**Addendum 1:**
With use of the `diagbox` library as is seems in the code fragment but by far shorter and correct code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example of \texttt{tabularray} table}
\footnotesize

    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[l, wd=33mm] * {5}{X[c]} },
                 colsep  = {4pt},
                 cell{1}{1} = {font=\tiny},
                 rows    = {m}
                 }
\diagbox{\parbox{15mm}{\raggedright Participation aux législatives}}
        {\parbox{15mm}{\raggedright Participation aux législatives}}
    &   A tous les tours
        &   Au 1  tour
            &   Au 2 tour
                &   Aucun
                    &   Total               \\
A tous les tours
    & 0,65  & 2,84  &       & 3,10  &       \\
Au 1{} tour
    &  0,13 & 0,29  & 0,26  & 0,08  &       \\
Au 2 tour
    &       & 1,13  & 1,25  & 0,60  & 0,36  \\
Total
    &       & 4,26  &       & 3,78  & 1,90  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 2:**

- Apparently the first version of your question was (a big confusion and consequently misleading what you after (therefore -1 for it from me) and my effort to help you was just waste of my time.
- Anyway both first two examples shows how can be with correctly and more concise way by strict dividing formatting  of table from its contents, avoided your problems (whatever they are).
- Your new table's code can be written on much more concise and correctly way. Based on codes from my previous examples, it can be:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Phénomènes aléatoires}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Fréquences conditionnelles en colonne}
La fréquence conditionnelle $f_{R}(P)=0,56$.

Cela signifie que, parmi la sous-population de référence des élèves refusés (R)  (\textbf{c'est la condition}) environ 56 \% viennent des séries professionnelles.

\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1} = {2}{solid},     hline{2-Z}={1-Z}{solid},
                 vline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},   vline{2-Z}={1-Z}{solid},
                 colspec={Q[3cm,c] Q[2.5cm,c, mode=dmath] },
                 cell{1}{2}={bg=gray!10},
                 cell{Z}{1}={bg=red!10},
                 row{1} = {mode=text}
                }
% table body
                    &   Refusé R        \\
Série générale G    &   \dfrac{14741}{65126}=0,23   \\
Série pro P         &   \dfrac{13687}{65126}=0,21   \\
Série techno P      &   \dfrac{36698}{65126}=0,56   \\
Total               & 1                             \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]